# How can i use the same sha512 of c# in java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, sha512

This is the code used in c#

```
public static string Encode_SHA512(string input) {
    try {
           using (SHA512 sha = SHA512.Create()) {
           byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));
           return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Error al generar hash SHA512", ex);
    }
}
```

And this is the code used in java (One of many attempts)

```
public static String Encode_SHA512(String input) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] digest = md.digest(input.getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
    return String.format("%0128x", new BigInteger(1, digest));
}
```

But always the result is different. How can I use the same encryption of the C # code in java?

Comment: Your code never converts to base64. If the error persists the cause might be different padding or char-encoding.

Comment: Please debug your code and figure out where difference come from. Make sure to get it working first for array of 4 bytes and than add sting-to-byte logic.

Comment: Are you quite certain that `input.getBytes("UTF-16LE")` and `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input)` are using the same encoding?

Comment: I'm not sure if its the same encoding, but the answer of Kevin Holditch is correct, I only need  convert to base64 and then the problem is solved, thank you very much to everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your Java version you are not converting to a base64 encoded string correctly.  If you update your Java code to the following then they both produce the same hash:

```
   public static String Encode_SHA512(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        byte [] inputBytes = input.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
        byte[] digest = md.digest(inputBytes);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);
    }
```

The line `return String.format("%0128x", new BigInteger(1, digest));` is replaced with `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(digest);` which currently base 64 encodes the resultant hash.  Perhaps why the code was confusing is that the `byte[]` produced by the `digest` method looked different as in Java the byte type is twos complement (which is signed) so -128 to + 127 whereas in C# it is unsigned so 0 to 255 hence in the debugger any byte with starting with a 1 would look different as it would appear negative in Java but positive in C#.